# Conversion from sql to sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create classes for sqlalchemy in order to make sqlalchemy create database Sometables.
Here is SQL code:

```
CREATE table "Sometable" (
    id INTEGER UNIQUE NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT NOT NULL, 
    database_id INTEGER REFERENCES databases (id) ON DELETE CASCADE NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT a UNIQUE (name, database_id) ON CONFLICT IGNORE
);
```

I have tried so far:

```
class Sometable(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(140))
    database_id = db.Column(db.Integer, 
    db.ForeignKeyConstraint("Sometable.database_id", "databases.id"))


class Databases(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(140))
```

and:

```
class Sometable(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    database_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKeyConstraint(["Sometable.database_id"], ["databases.id"]))


class Databases(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
```

and:

```
class Sometable(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    database_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("databases.id"))
    db.ForeignKeyConstraint(["database_id"], ["databases.id"])


class Databases(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
```

and I cannot figure out how to do it. When I do flask db init; migrate; upgrade I  receive schema of Sometable:

```
CREATE TABLE Sometable(
        id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        name VARCHAR,
        database_id INTEGER,
        PRIMARY KEY (id),
        FOREIGN KEY(database_id) REFERENCES databases (id)
```

@Edit
and also tried:

```
class Sometable(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    database_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("databases.id"))
    db.ForeignKeyConstraint(["database_id"], ["databases.id"])
    db.UniqueConstraint("name", "database_id")


class Databases(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
```

Comment: What did you expect to see happen, and what actually happened?

Comment: @brunns I have updated question. The generated table by sqlalchemy is not the same as desired one.